# Marshmallow - dex2oat ~ permission denied

Tags: dex2oat

Got forced close when trying to start CameraApp:

```
08-15 15:36:19.807 E/dex2oat (29758): Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@priv-app@LGCameraApp@LGCameraApp.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
```

- the file does exist on the stated path, why is it trying to dex2oat again?
- suspect this app also gets "optimized" every time when the phone boots up

Can logcat provide boot-up app optimization log?  Which keyword should I look for?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Got Any Solution?